# How to get data that is not present in inspect element but rendered on browser?

Tags: python, selenium

Normally I'd use find_elements_by_class_name or id but there's .. nothing there to grab. If anybody can shed some lights on how this page is rendered I'd be really thankful.

Data present in browser but not in in inspect element :

[image: Data present in browser but not in in inspect element]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how you'd grab it with selenium, but the element you see in the HTML code is just a placeholder element that is replaced or modified in some javascript code elsewhere. From the screenshot that you've sent, I can see that it has an ID of "md-input-bj7750fcw". That is probably what's being used to grab it in the javascript code. You could search through the files on the sources tab and find which bit of the js changes it.